# What happens when a lycanthrope bites a lycanthrope of different species?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

What will happen when a werelizard bites a dwarf that is already infected by a weregoat? 
Does it matter if the dwarf is in weregoat form during the biting?

Comment: Only in Dwarf Fortress...

Comment: @Frank: Not true: Nethack also has this (although replace weregoat/werelizard with jackal, wolf, and one or two others).  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3654/bitten-by-a-vampire-werewolf-and-zombie-what-happens-to-him has an answer that references the nethack behavior

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having a were-curse prevents the target from collecting any other were-curse, among other things. So... nothing besides normal bite damage.

I've checked the raws in /raw/interaction examples.txt, the were-curse definition cannot apply to: vampires, not-living creatures (aka elementals and bronze colossi), supernatural creatures, other were-cursed, and people who were cursed by a mummy. Actually, all curses - were, vampire and mummy - exclude each other. Pity.

```
[INTERACTION:WEREBEAST_CURSE]
[I_TARGET:A:CREATURE]
    snip
    [IT_FORBIDDEN:NOT_LIVING]
    [IT_FORBIDDEN:SUPERNATURAL]
    [IT_CANNOT_HAVE_SYNDROME_CLASS:WERECURSE]
    [IT_CANNOT_HAVE_SYNDROME_CLASS:VAMPCURSE]
    [IT_CANNOT_HAVE_SYNDROME_CLASS:DISTURBANCE_CURSE]
```